# Collapsable/dropdown Pane in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I saw it somewhere and I'm not even sure what it's called, but I'm looking for a way of creating a separator with an arrow-like button
[image: separator with button]
which upon click would drop second part of the upper Pane, like so:
[image: Frame with visible lower Pane]
Then, you could click it again to hide the lower part.

Is there any ready-to-use component with this functionality?

Comment: Nice images. Do you have impressive paint skills or a mock-up tool which features an extremely bad handwritten font ?

Comment: @Robin it's handmade on my smartphone. I have my drawing app synced with pc, so whenever I need it I instantaneously have .tiffs available. I found it to be way faster and easier than Paint or any other tool. Thanks for my personal font evaluation though :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JXCollapsiblePane` from the SwingX project might be what you are looking for. This has to functionality to collapse and expand in an animated way.

The `JXTaskPane` is an alternative where the UI components to expand/collapse are already present.

Consult the javadoc of those classes for more information. SwingX version 1.6.5-1 can be downloaded from [here](https://search.maven.org/#browse%7C764423309).